# Responsive web design ccs button works in desktop view but not any reaction with mobile view

Tags: html, css

support me for set link on the button that works in both responsive mode.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-learn">Get now <i class="icon-arrow-right3"></i></button>
```

I tried this also..

```
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-learn">send Request <i class="icon-arrow-right3"></i></a></p>
```

in this original code where i should include link

Comment: Please include the relevant code to recreate the issue within your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is your error?
Don't forget put your code.
btw let's use class `btn .....` for a tag

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about CSS and it not applying on mobile, but you haven't shown us any of the CSS so we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to add a link, in the second piece of code add an **`href`** parameter, like so:

```
<p><a href="http://your-link-here.com/" class="btn btn-primary btn-learn">send Request <i class="icon-arrow-right3"></i></a></p>
```